# creating array of bad names to check and replace in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking to create a method that loops through an list and replaces with matched values with a new value. I have something working below but it really doesnt follow the DRY principal and looks ugly.

How could I create a dictionary of value pairs that would hold my data of values to match and replace?

```
           var match = acreData.data;

            foreach(var i in match)
            {   
                if (i.county_name == "DE KALB")
                {
                    i.county_name = "DEKALB";
                }
                if (i.county_name == "DU PAGE")
                {
                    i.county_name = "DUPAGE";
                }
             }
```

Comment: Start with `new Dictionary..`, add values to it, and then use [`TryGetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: That said, in this case, would it not be sufficient to "remove white space"? If such is valid/sufficient depends on the entire problem space. One issue with the dictionary (or if/else approach) is that it is a *whitelisting* whereas removing white space is, for better or worse, more generalized.. (and it might be the case that the two can be used in tandem: eg. remove white space and perform alias mappings).

Comment: *How could I create a dictionary of value pairs*  [MSDN is an excellent resource.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2). Dictionary classes are thoroughly documented and have example uses.

Comment: Depending on where all the data resides, I have sometimes employed an *Alias* system where there is an official name and then as many aliases as needed.  Then at as low of level as possible, a detected alias is replaced with the official name

Comment: Also future proof this, by storing this in a db, or at least a file, so you dont have to rebuild your code all the time, load it up in to memory as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, you can try to use linq and `Replace` to make it.

```
var match = acreData.data.ToList();
match.ForEach(x =>
    x.county_name = x.county_name.Replace(" ", "")
);
```

or you can try to create a mapper table to let your data mapper with your value. as @user2864740 say.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("DE KALB", "DEKALB");
dict.Add("DU PAGE", "DUPAGE");

var match = acreData.data;
string val = string.Empty;
foreach (var i in match)
{
    if (dict.TryGetValue(i.county_name, out val))
        i.county_name = val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this were my problem and it is possible a county could have more than one common misspelling I would create a class to hold the correct name and the common misspellings. The you could easily determine if the misspelling exists and correct if. Something like this:

```
public class County
{
    public string CountyName { get; set; }
    public List<string> CommonMisspellings { get; set; }

    public County()
    {
        CommonMisspellings = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
//most likely populate from db
var counties = new List<County>();
var dekalb = new County { CountyName = "DEKALB" };

dekalb.CommonMisspellings.Add("DE KALB");
dekalb.CommonMisspellings.Add("DE_KALB");

var test = "DE KALB";

if (counties.Any(c => c.CommonMisspellings.Contains(test)))
{
    test = counties.First(c => c.CommonMisspellings.Contains(test)).CountyName;
}
```

Comment: This does not scale well. Hopefully number of misspellings is low and it would be less than thousand times slower than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply replacing all words in a list containing space without space, then can use below:

```
var newList = match.ConvertAll(word => word.Replace(" ", ""));
```

[ConvertAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.convertall?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns a new list.

Also, I suggest not to use variable names like i, j, k etc..but use temp etc.

**Sample code below:**

```
var oldList = new List<string> {"DE KALB", "DE PAGE"};
var newList = oldList.ConvertAll(word => word.Replace(" ", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try removing all the characters but letters and apostroph (`Cote d'Ivoire` has it)

```
...
i.country_name = String.Concat(i.country_name
  .Where(c => char.IsLetter(c) || c == '\''));
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a comment under answer of @Kevin and it seems it needs further explanation. Sequential searching in list does not scale well and unfortunately for Kevin, that is not my opinion, asymptotic computational complexity is math. While searching in dictionary is more or less O(1), searching in list is O(n). To show a practical impact for solution with 100 countries with 100 misspellings each, lets make a test

```
public class Country
{
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public List<string> CommonMisspellings { get; set; }

    public Country()
    {
        CommonMisspellings = new List<string>();
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    var counties = new List<Country>();
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    List<string> allCountryNames = new List<string>();
    List<string> allMissNames = new List<string>();

    for (int state = 0; state < 100; ++state)
    {
        string countryName = state.ToString() + rnd.NextDouble();
        allCountryNames.Add(countryName);
        var country = new Country { CountryName = countryName };
        counties.Add(country);

        for (int miss = 0; miss < 100; ++miss)
        {
            string missname = countryName + miss;
            allMissNames.Add(missname);
            country.CommonMisspellings.Add(missname);
            dict.Add(missname, countryName);
        }
    }

    List<string> testNames = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    {
        if (rnd.Next(20) == 1)
        {
            testNames.Add(allMissNames[rnd.Next(allMissNames.Count)]);
        }
        else
        {
            testNames.Add(allCountryNames[rnd.Next(allCountryNames.Count)]);
        }
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch st = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    st.Start();

    List<string> repairs = new List<string>();
    foreach (var test in testNames)
    {
        if (counties.Any(c => c.CommonMisspellings.Contains(test)))
        {
            repairs.Add(counties.First(c => c.CommonMisspellings.Contains(test)).CountryName);
        }
    }

    st.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("List approach: " + st.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + "ms");

    st = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    st.Start();

    List<string> repairsDict = new List<string>();
    foreach (var test in testNames)
    {
        if (dict.TryGetValue(test, out var val))
        {
            repairsDict.Add(val);
        }
    }

    st.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Dict approach: " + st.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + "ms");

    Console.WriteLine("Repaired count: " + repairs.Count
        + ", check " + (repairs.SequenceEqual(repairsDict) ? "OK" : "ERROR"));

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And the result is

> ```
> List approach: 7264ms
> Dict approach: 4ms
> Repaired count: 4968, check OK
> ```

List approach is about 1800x slower, actually more the thousand times slower in this case. The results are as expected. If that is a problem is another question, it depends on concrete usage pattern in concrete application and is out of scope of this post.